# il prezzo si è dimezzato vs. il prezzo è dimezzato

Tags: grammar

> Il prezzo del petrolio *si* è ormai dimezzato rispetto a giugno scorso, ma quello dei carburanti è sceso a malapena del 10%.

Ritenete che il 'si' sia necessario in questa frase?

Answer (score 6):

Non è indispensabile, ma va benissimo: vedi la [voce “dimezzare” sul Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/dimezzare/), per cui “dimezzarsi” significa “ridursi alla metà”.

Con o senza “si” si hanno due sfumature appena diverse: “si è dimezzato” è un'azione, ancorché compiuta da un oggetto inanimato, e dà un'idea lievemente più dinamica di “è dimezzato”, che dice solo che ora è la metà di allora. In altre parole: nel primo caso ”si è ridotto alla metà”, nel secondo “è pari alla metà”.

Comment: Concordo sulla spiegazione, ma ritengo che quel "si" sia indispensabile. La frase "Il prezzo del petrolio è dimezzato" non suona bene alle mie orecchio. Suonerebbe bene solo se ci fosse anche il soggetto che causa l'azione: "Il prezzo del petrolio è dimezzato dalla scarsissima richiesta".